# how to set css width equal to length of longest text

Tags: css, width

I have quite a challenging task.

I have this menu here... http://jsfiddle.net/K2Zzh/6/

If you hover over 'treatments', the width for the dropdown menu is set at 150px, which is fine, however, if you hover over 'aftercare', you can see this width is too wide. I have tried min-width, auto, inline-block, but no luck so far.

Rather than creating a separate class for each dropdown, is there a clever way of setting the width to only be as large as the longest text per menu?

The css code i have used for the drop down...

```
.dropdown ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 43px;
  z-index: 100;
  border-left: 1px solid #f6634c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f6634c;
  border-right: 1px solid #f6634c;
}
.dropdown ul li a {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
}​
```

Thanks in advance.

My HTML Code...

```
<ul class="mainNav">
  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="">Treatments</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Body Treatments</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Make Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Skincare</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Hand & Feet Treats</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Hair Removal</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Alternative Therapies</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Eye Enhancements</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="">Aftercare</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Body</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Make up</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Skin</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Hand</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could add to the question the relevant HTML markup as well. A jsfiddle link is great and helps a lot, but if the link rots this question very much less  useful to future visitors.

Comment: ok will do in future, thanks for the tip

Comment: Thanks! But why not start *now*? You can edit your question at any time to improve/clarify it, so future visitors would benefit as well from the answers!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

*first step:* remove fixed width from `.dropdown ul li a`

*second step:* add the css `li li {width:100%;}`

*third step:* add `.mainNav li a {white-space:nowrap;}`

**It's ready:** http://jsfiddle.net/K2Zzh/10/

​

Comment: This is by far the best answer, thank you, this is pretty clever

Answer (score 9):

Try `white-space: nowrap` and `width: auto` in your `.dropdown ul li a` class

http://jsfiddle.net/K2Zzh/8/

Answer (score 0):

Put the width to "li" instead of "a" , and you can use padding too

```
.dropdown ul li {
    width: auto;
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
}​
```

i think it should works