# Using css to set width of <li> with content

Tags: css

I need some help...here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/taglegacy/Lrczay80/.

I'm trying to get the width of the li to match that of the longest text within the li. I've tried using this solution although I can't seem to make it work for my css code, [how to set css width equal to length of longest text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903929/how-to-set-css-width-equal-to-length-of-longest-text).

If you can help that would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the CSS:

```
ol.nlist
{
counter-reset: li;
padding: 10px;
}

ol.nlist li
{
position: relative;
margin: 0 0 0px 2em;
padding: 4px 8px;
list-style: none;
border-top: 2px solid #af1f1c;
background: #f6f6f6;
}

ol.nlist li:before
{
content: counter(li);
counter-increment: li; 
position: absolute;
top: -2px;
left: -2em;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 2em;
margin-right: 8px;
padding: 4px;
height: 30px;
border-top: 2px solid #af1f1c;
color: #fff;
background: #af1f1c;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}

li.nlist ol, li.nlist ul
{
margin-top: 6px;
width: 100%;
}

ol.nlist ol li:last-child
{
margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ac
{
text-decoration: none;
color: #444;
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<ol class="nlist">
<li><a class="ac" href="#1">Test Short Text</a></li>
<li><a class="ac" href="#2">Slightly Longer Text to Test</a></li>
<li><a class="ac" href="#3">Really Really Long Long Long Text to Give the Effect  Wanted</a></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add these `display: table; table-layout: fixed;` to your `ol`:

```
ol.nlist
{
    counter-reset: li; /* Initiate a counter */
    padding: 10px;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrczay80/4/)

Note that `table-layout: fixed;` is optional. Its more for a performance improvement than style.

Comment: And set the width to 'auto'

Comment: Or remove it completely like you did :D

Comment: What does initiating a counter do?

Comment: Dunno, I just used the original CSS and added my two properties.

Comment: @Dan It counts the rows of li starting from 1.

Comment: @Mrchief Thanks! I would have chosen this as an answer earlier, had to wait 4mins and 23sec...lol! To everyone that commented thank you for every solutions that you provided! Never turn down help when help is needed! :)

Comment: Ha ha.. keep overflowing the stack and you shall be rewarded! :)

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
ol.nlist li
{
position: relative;
margin: 0 0 0px 2em;
padding: 4px 8px;
list-style: none;
border-top: 2px solid #af1f1c;
background: #f6f6f6;
width: 760px;
}
```

to this:

```
ol.nlist li
{
position: relative;
margin: 0 0 0px 2em;
padding: 4px 8px;
list-style: none;
border-top: 2px solid #af1f1c;
background: #f6f6f6;
width: auto;
}
```

Comment: I tried that already, I edited out the width: 760px; when I noticed it. I was trying to get as close as I can, although now I need the same css for another list and it uses shorter text.

Auto by the way sends it all the way across the page.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
ol.nlist
{
counter-reset: li; /* Initiate a counter */
padding: 10px;
}
```

to this:

```
ol.nlist
{
counter-reset: li; /* Initiate a counter */
padding: 10px;
display:table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To `ol.nlist`, add `position: absolute;`

In `ol.nlist li`, remove the `width` and add the following two properties:

```
display: block;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Here's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/y1cv84c3/