# complex html nav menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav

I'd like a menu so that the drop down goes over the menu at a small width.

Here it goes for those of you who like a challenge. Here's what I got:

```css
nav{
 line-height:100%;
 opacity:.9;
}nav ul{
 background: #999;
  padding: 0px;
 border-radius: 20px;  
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-table;
}nav ul ul{
 display: none;
 background: #567;
 border-radius: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
}nav ul li{
 float: left;
}nav ul li a{
 display: block;
 padding: 25px 40px;
 color: #666;
 text-decoration: none;
}nav ul li:hover{
 background: #345;
}nav ul li:hover a{
 color: #fff;
}nav ul li:hover>ul{
 display: block;
}nav ul ul li{
 float: none; 
 border-top: 1px solid #567;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #678;
 position: relative;
}nav ul ul li a{
 padding: 15px 40px;
 color: #fff;
}nav ul ul li a:hover{
 background: #456;
}nav ul ul ul{
 position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
 
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <h3>
   <li><a href="otherpage.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="otherpage.html">Page2</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="otherpage.html">Page2.1</a></li>
     <li><a href="otherpage.html">Page2.2</a></li>
     <li><a href="otherpage.html">Page2.3</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="otherpage.html">Page2.3.1</a></li>
       <li><a href="otherpage.html">Page2.3.2</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="otherpage.html">Page3</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="otherpage.html">Page3.1</a></li>
     <li><a href="otherpage.html">Page3.2</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="otherpage.html">Page4</a></li>
   </h3>
  </ul>
 </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

I'd like a nav menu that does what I have so far, but so that the drop down goes over the rest of the menu when at a small width. Sort of like this: [how to set css width equal to length of longest text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903929/how-to-set-css-width-equal-to-length-of-longest-text).

I don't know too much but would this require javascript? I'd also appreciate the javascript dropdown effect similar to the link but that isn't necessary.

If you don't understand my problem, please run my code fullscreen, then decrease the width of your browser, so that the dropdown isn't clickable.

Bonus points for making the text spacing even as the width adjusts.

Thanks

Comment: What i have understood is that you want a responsive navbar which on resize resizes itself? Is that what you want?

Comment: not really. I want it so that when it does resize itself that it still works as a menu, so that people can click on the drop down links. right now the drop down is eclipsed by the rest of the menu at small widths

Comment: Why don't you use bootstrap responsive navbar? It has all you need.

Comment: what's that? sorry, there's a lot i don't know...

Comment: try this --> http://jsfiddle.net/incrediblex/n0yfd22v/1/

Comment: not exactly what i'm looking for, but it's cool. i'm gonna sound stupid now, but i copied that onto an html doc and it didn't work. what's the additional package or whatever that i'm missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69980/discussion-between-justin-and-subhan-ahmed).

Comment: I've answered a few details about bootstrap. Please accept the answer if you think that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You liked bootstrap so here is a quick intro.

> Bootstrap (front-end framework) Bootstrap is a free collection of
>   tools for creating websites and web applications. It contains HTML and
>   CSS-based design templates for typography, forms, buttons, navigation
>   and other interface components, as well as optional JavaScript
>   extensions.

You need to include these paths to your code to use its functionality:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You can also download bootstrap [here](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Different components for bootstrap are listed [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/)

Try Googling it to know more about it.