# Set width of CSS class based on longest string in array

Tags: html, css, angular

Angular coders may recognize this code as a modified [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) project. How do I set the width of the "badge" CSS class dynamically such that all badges in the `ul` are the same width, fitting the longest id? So, the badge width property should be 2ch with the given dummy data which currently has a max length of 2.

Template

```
<ul class="contacts">
  <li *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
    <a routerLink="/detail/{{contact.id}}">
      <span class="badge">{{contact.id}}</span>{{contact.name}}
    </a>
    <button title="Delete contact" (click)="delete(contact)">x</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.contacts .badge {
  color: white;
  background-color: #607D8B;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 2ch;
  padding: 0 1ch 0 1ch;
}
```

Dummy data

```
const contacts = [
  { id: 1, name: 'John McClane' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Holly Gennero' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Harry Ellis' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Karl Vreski' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Al Powell' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Tony Vreski' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Theo' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Agent Johnson' },
  { id: 9, name: 'Special Agent Johnson' },
  { id: 10, name: 'Dwayne T. Robinson' },
  { id: 11, name: 'Yoshinobu Takagi' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Hans Gruber'}
];
```

I've tried to style the page based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13904086/3853136) but no such luck. If possible, I prefer keep the styling in CSS rather than setting the width programmatically in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the the width of the `span` and use `display:flex` in the anchor tag

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.contacts .badge {
  color: white;
  background-color: #607D8B;
  width: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 1ch 0 1ch;
}

.contacts li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.contacts li a {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul class="contacts">
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="badge">1</span>John McClane
    </a>
    <button title="Delete contact" (click)="delete(contact)">x</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="badge">9</span>Special Agent Johnson
    </a>
    <button title="Delete contact" (click)="delete(contact)">x</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="badge">11</span>Yoshinobu Takagi
    </a>
    <button title="Delete contact" (click)="delete(contact)">x</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Kind of you to respond. This answer isn't quite what I'm looking for however. Here you have hard-coded the width to 24px. Which works for small id number, but won't widen _all_ badges automatically as my number id grows in length. If you have any ideas and can amend the answer please do.

Comment: I wasn't clear that I was using flex already with the CSS `.contacts * {display:flex;}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to slightly change the HTML struture you can use table like this:

```css
.contacts {
  display: table;
}

.contacts li {
  display: table-row;
}

.contacts li span,
.contacts li a,
.contacts li button {
  display: table-cell;
}

.contacts .badge {
  color: white;
  background-color: #607D8B;
  padding: 0 1ch 0 1ch;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<ul class="contacts">
  <li>
    <span class="badge">1</span>
    <a>
      John McClane
    </a>
    <button title="Delete contact">x</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="badge">9</span>
    <a>
      Special Agent Johnson
    </a>
    <button title="Delete contact">x</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="badge">1001</span>
    <a>
      Yoshinobu Takagi
    </a>
    <button title="Delete contact">x</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think you have the right idea @temani. This might be better displayed as a table. I plan to look into your method soon to determine if there is any reason flex is necessary.

Comment: @AaronBorns well flex or any other technique is never necessary :) it always depend on your needs ;) ... by the way here i applied table to all the element so even the button are correctly aligned based on the longest text ... so if you want the button to be close to text you can remove display:cell from `a` element ;)

Comment: I did notice that and appreciate its merits. :) I noticed just now you took the span outside of the anchor, which means the anchor's routerLink will not respond to clicks on the id number itself. I understand why this was done for the table to work, but I want the behavior of clicks on the id to goto the routerLink destination. Any tips?

Comment: @AaronBorns yes this was the small drawback :) well an idea is to wrap the span of the badge in the another `a` so you have two of them